# SQL performance of a select statement as a column

Tags: sql

I have a sql query,

```
SELECT 
  col1, 
  col2, 
  col3, (
    SELECT COUNT(id) 
    FROM B 
    WHERE B.aid = A.id
  ) AS col4 
FROM A
```

What is the performance impact of having a select as a column? Will that statement be executed for every row that is returned?

I am really just interested in the performance of this query. I know there are other ways getting the count can be accomplished. But in this case I am only trying to understand how sql works with an inline select.

Apologies if this question is a dupe, I have looked through stackoverflow and I have not been able to find this anywhere.

Comment: Implementation dependant. Please state RDBMS.

Comment: If you are using SQL Server you can use SSMS and select to show estimated or actual execution plan of this query versus using an INNER  or OUTER JOIN to table b. This will show any impact of one over the other.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This depends upon your SQL implementation.

SQL is declarative and it is up to the optimiser to construct a physical plan from the logical specification. SQL Server can [decorrelate this sub query](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/craigfr/archive/2006/10/04/decorrelating-subqueries.aspx) and turn into an `OUTER JOIN`

```
CREATE TABLE A(id INT PRIMARY KEY, col1 INT, col2 INT, col3 INT)

CREATE TABLE B(aid INT)

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX ix ON B(aid)

/*Fool optimiser into thinking tables aren't empty*/
update statistics A with rowcount = 1000000, pagecount = 100000

update statistics B with rowcount = 1000000, pagecount = 100000

SELECT col1,
       col2,
       col3,
       (SELECT count( B.aid)
        FROM   B
        WHERE  B.aid = A.id) AS col4
FROM   A 

DROP TABLE A, B
```

Gives plan

[image: Plan]

Which is basically the same as

```
SELECT col1,
       col2,
       col3,
       Cnt
FROM   (SELECT COUNT(aid) AS Cnt,
               aid
        FROM   B
        GROUP  BY aid) T
       RIGHT OUTER JOIN A
         ON A.id = T.aid
```

The sub query is logically represented as a `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` with `MERGE JOIN` as the physical implementation. The merge join processes each input once rather than the row by row behaviour of a nested loops join.